# What is the best way to check if related entity exists in EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have two entities with one-to-zero-or-one relation: `Version` and `ChangeLog`. The second one stores file with changelog (for example 'ReadMe.html').

```
public class Version 
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ChangeLog ChangeLog { get; set; }
}

public class ChangeLog 
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public byte[] File { get; set; }

    public int VersionId { get; set; }
    public Version Version { get; set; }
}
```

Code for one-to-one relation:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Version>()
            .HasOne(v => v.ChangeLog)
            .WithOne(c => c.Version)
            .HasForeignKey<ChangeLog>(c => c.VersionId);
```

How to check if related entity exists. So for the one-to-many relation I could do things like this `Product.Versions.Any()`.
What about one-to-one? Should I use a context `context.ChangeLogs.Any(c => c.VersionId == versionId)`?

Comment: `Version.ChangeLog != null`

Comment: I should load related entity in this case. I want to check it on the server side if it's possible.

Comment: What do you think the "server side" does? Queries the DB against that entity and returns either the entity or empty result set.

Comment: Actually I don't want to get data from Sql server, just to know if it exists. So the way you suggested force me to download the file.

Comment: Then `Any()` is one good solution

Comment: If you can add `int? ChangeLogId` in `Version` model and remove the explicit FK declaration `HasForeignKey` in the `modeBuilder`, then it would be easy to check if ChangeLog exists by using `...v.ChangeLogId.HasValue())...`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by doing the following:

1. when you query for the '`Version`' entity, ensure you also request the '`ChangeLog`' entity, as follows.

   ```
   var versionWithChangeLog = context.Versions.Include(v => v.ChangeLog)
                                     .FirstOrDefault(v => v.Id == versionid);
   ```
2. this ensures that EF always tries to pull the related `ChangeLog` entity for the `Version` entity.
3. now do a null check on the related `ChangeLog` entity.

   ```
    if (versionWithChangeLog && versionWithChangeLog.ChangeLog != null)
    {
       // we got  a version entity with a changelog.
    }
   ```

basically if there is a related record, EF will always pull it, since we asked it to. And if it is null, that means the database did not have a record.

Ohh, and if you want to just check if the related changelog entity exists or not, and not retrieve it, you can use these:

```
var versionsWithChangeLog = context.Versions.Where(v => v.ChangeLog != null);

var versionsWithoutChangeLog = context.Versions.Where(v => v.ChangeLog == null);
```

Comment: I think that is an expensive operation. I can store large object there.

Comment: @SergеуIsupov makes sense. if you just want to check it, you can just use the predicates, not retrieve the entities.. the whole check is at the SQL engine side, so no data should be retrieved for ChangeLog.